# Advice/Help on resetting a large number of iOS and MacOS devices

Tags: mac-osx, ios, iphone, ipad, reset

We have a unique challenge with our in house iOS and MacOS devices.

Specifically, we have accumulated dozens of iPhones, iPads, MacBook Airs and Macbook Pros (~35-40 total) for which we dont have passwords (Macs), PINs and Restriction Codes (iPads, iPhones) and iCloud accounts for which we no longer have passwords. These are in our IT storage closet for now and it takes us several hours trying to get them up and running before handing off to new employees, etc.

Is there a way for us to reset all these devices back to factory settings so we set them up fresh again?

Open to paid (software), outsourced (3rd party company/Apple store) assistance.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Inventory what you have. And what you don't have, if there were important documents on inaccessible accounts or devices.

Decide on policy, such as device security, how to authenticate, and what software to install and configure. See the [Mac deployment overview](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/Mac_Deployment_Overview.pdf) for an summary.

Then implement that policy with mobile device management (MDM), scripting and automation. Server Fault doesn't do recommendations, up to you to pick something that meets your requirements and try it.

It won't be zero touch provisioning on devices purchased without [automatic enrollment](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204142). But you can reset and manually add devices. An hour hands on may be fine if you don't need to touch it again.